# Can I create a C2 instance Notebook in AI Platform?

Tags: gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I tried to create a C2 instance in AI Platform notebooks, but is not shown in UI, is this Compute Instance supported?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CLI:

```
gcloud beta notebooks instances create c2-nb '--machine-type=c2-standard-4' '--vm-image-project=deeplearning-platform-release' '--vm-image-family=common-cpu-notebooks' '--location=us-central1-a'
```